# XCode is lagging when typing?

Tags: xcode

When using Xcode, does anyone else experience text lagging to be seen when typing.
Or the mouse, when you scroll, it catches or lags for a second.

Is this my computer or Xcode?

Comment: same problem here. It could very well be a computer problem, but can't really see what it would be. I installed the new system on my new mac book pro, just like I always did and xCode started lagging from the start.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds very much like a computer issue, to pinpoint it you could use a similar program and see if the mouse lag is still there. I'm pretty sure that the xcode developers did not invent something to make the mouse lag at least.